# How can I apply a smooth mousewheel scroll effect to the text/content of two separate sections in Elementor?

Tags: fadein, mousewheel, smooth-scrolling

I'd like to implement smooth scrolling with fade-in and fade-out effects for two distinct sections in Elementor.

I experimented with a scrolling effect that involved fading in content by adjusting the transparency settings in the widget's advanced tab. Additionally, I applied a z-index value of 9999 along with a sticky top position to ensure compatibility with all devices.